# Scraping website for stock data with custom attribute tags

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information from investing.com based on the ISIN number of the stock.

So far I have this:

```
Sub Get_Stock_Data()

  Dim Page As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim Doc As New HTMLDocument
  Dim inputbox As IHTMLElement

  Dim Table As IHTMLElement
  Dim Row As IHTMLElement
  Dim cel As IHTMLElement

  Page.Open "get", "https://www.investing.com/", False
  Page.send

  Doc.body.innerHTML = Page.responseText

  Set inputbox = Doc.getElementById("searchTextTop")
  inputbox.Value = "US0378331005"

  Set Table = Doc.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)

  For Each cel In Table.getElementsByTagName("td")
      Debug.Print cel.tagName, cel.className, cel.getAttribute("link")
  Next
End Sub
```

The ISIN number is being entered into the main search box of the web page which consists of the following elements:

```
<form onsubmit="" id="combineSearchFormTop" action="/" method="post">    
   <div class="inlineblock" id="searchBoxTop">       
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="EUR/USD or AAPL" 
     default="EUR/USD or AAPL" class="searchText arial_12 lightgrayFont" 
     id="searchTextTop" name="quotes_search_text" prevvalue="">
   </div>
   <label for="searchTextTop" class="searchGlassIcon">&nbsp;</label>
   <i class="cssSpinner"></i>
</form>
```

An autocomplete table is generated after the ISIN number is entered into the search box. It contains the necessary query string to proceed to the main page of the stock. Here is the HTML segment that contains the required info.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-pair-id="6408" class="row hoverSearch" id="searchRowIdtop_0"> 
      <td class="first flag"><i class="ceFlags USA"></i></td> 
      <td class="second symbolName dirLtr" pairid="6408" id="symbol_AAPL" 
      link="/equities/apple-computer-inc">AAPL</td>                      
      <td class="third" title="Apple Inc">Apple Inc</td>
      <td class="fourth typeExchange" pairid="6408" id="type_6408" 
      link="/equities/apple-computer-inc">Equity - NASDAQ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

I want to get the string from the "link" attribute of the second `<td>` tag. However, when I run the code in Excel the immediate window returns "null" for the "link" attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I provided the HTML used in order to search for the ISIN number.

Comment: I am not quite sure why I should use the `click` method since I am not using Internet explorer. Also, the other attributes in the `debug.print` statement are being read correctly, it is only the "link" attribute that is not, presumably because it a custom one.

Comment: So should I forgo using XML all together and use Internet Explorer instead?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below example. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://www.investing.com/search/service/search", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "search_text=US0378331005"
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    vJSON = vJSON("All")
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The output with `search_text` parameter set as `US0378331005` for me as follows:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).